# Exit application on back button using getOnBackPressedDispatcher

Tags: java, android, back-button

To override the back button's action in API below 33, one could use

```
@Override
public void OnBackPressed(){
  finish();
}
```

Now that this has been deprecated, I am trying to get the getOnBackPressedDispatcher to work.

From my first activity, I start a second one using the call back for a button:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openSecondActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Now, in the second activity, I want the back button to exit the app.

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed(){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This, however, doesn't work. Pressing the back button takes me back to the first activity.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you call finish on your first activity when you move to the second one?

Comment: You are right. I tried that and it worked. Thanks. Post your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close your first activity when moving to the second one, by calling finish.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void openSecondActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();       /// <----- HERE
 }
}
```

Also, I would recommend reading up on [launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element).